# remove last append element jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I have the following code:

```
$(this).children("a:eq(0)").append('<img src="'+ (arrowsvar.down[1]) 
    +'" class="' + (arrowsvar.down[0])
    + '" style="border:0;" />'
);
```

Now I want to remove last appended element (an image). Please give suggestions.

Answer (score 58):

As an alternative, for those who likes more programmatic ways and syntax:

```
$('#container-element img').last().remove();
```

Answer (score 36):

You can use the [:last-child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild) selector to find the last appended element, then you can [remove](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) it:

```
$('img:last-child', this).remove();
// get the last img element of the childs of 'this'
```

Answer (score 20):

The code from the original question may generate errors (using "this" with the selector). Try the following approach:

```
$("#container-element img:last-child").remove()
```

Comment: If we want to remove all the elements that we appended last time ??

Comment: You might want to avoid using the expression "The above code" as that might change.

Answer (score 6):

amazing, thank you very much eugene, that really helped me. I had to remove a table, i used the following code.

```
$("#mydivId table:last-child").remove()
```

Comment: This should be a comment to eugene's answer, not a separate answer in itself.

Answer (score 2):

try this. Just added .not(':last-child') which excludes the last element in your collection. So you don't have to remove it.

```
$(this).children("a:eq(0)").not(':last-child').append('<img src="'+ (arrowsvar.down[1]) 
    +'" class="' + (arrowsvar.down[0])
    + '" style="border:0;" />'
);
```