# removing last child of parent using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a parent div called examples. I want to remove the last div in that parent div. How can I do so using jquery?

```
<div class="examples">
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test2"></div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the last child of examples, which in this case is test2 div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove last append element jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650463/remove-last-append-element-jquery)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `find` to traverse the child elements. Use `div:last` to select the last one, and `.remove` to remove it.

```
$(".examples").find("div:last").remove();
```

Answer (score 4):

try this one:

`$('div.examples').children().last().remove();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.examples').children().last().remove()
```

Comment: has most legal look

Answer (score 1):

Just use `:last` filter.

```
$('.examples div:last').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2a94hc90/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last child of parent div is removed on clicking inner divs, try this one

> $(this).parent().children().last().remove();

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:nth-last-of-type()` selector with parameter `1`

```js
$(".examples div:nth-last-of-type(1)").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="examples">
  <div class="test1">test1</div>
  <div class="test2">test2</div>
</div>
```